# Unrecognized statement type. (near "IF" at position 0) - usage IF LIKE and LIKE

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

everbody. I have prooblem with LIKE in IF construction. I have the following query SQL:

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.ID_SPORTSMAN, a.NAME, a.SURNAME, a.SEX, a.CLUB, b.RESULTS 
FROM `sportsman` AS `a` 
JOIN `results` AS `b` 
ON a.ID_SPORTSMAN = b.ID_SPORTSMAN AND b.ID_DISCIPLINE = '1' ORDER BY b.RESULTS;
IF (b.RESULTS LIKE '`%')
THEN
   ASC LIMIT 10
ELSE   
   DESC LIMIT 10
END IF
```

I usage MariaDB. In phpmyadmin return me this error:

> Error
>
> Static analysis:
>
> 1 errors were found during analysis.
>
> ```
> Unrecognized statement type. (near "IF" at position 0)
> ```
>
> SQL query:
>
> IF (b.REZULTAT LIKE '`%') THEN ASC LIMIT 10 ELSE DESC LIMIT 10 END IF
>
> MySQL said: Documentation
>   1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'ASC LIMIT 10 ELSE      DESC LIMIT 10 END IF' at line 3

What is wrong?

Comment: Your logic doesn't even make sense.  What are you trying to do?

Comment: Ignoring syntax errors, What are you trying to achieve with `b.RESULTS LIKE '%'`??

Comment: I need to sort the search results. If it finds in the " ` " character 'it will use the ASC, if not DESC

Comment: In column RESULTS I have results sportman in many discipline(jumb, sprint etc).

Comment: @NinjaMaker - Please add some sample data and expected result..

Comment: Only expressions can be used in a `CASE`, not syntax (`ASC`, `LIMIT`, etc).  But it was inventive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using `case` in the `order by`:

```
select distinct s.ID_SPORTSMAN,
    s.name,
    s.SURNAME,
    s.SEX,
    s.CLUB,
    r.RESULTS
from sportsman as s
join results as r on s.ID_SPORTSMAN = r.ID_SPORTSMAN
where r.ID_DISCIPLINE = '1'
order by case 
        when r.RESULTS like '`%'
            then r.RESULTS
        end asc,
    r.RESULTS desc limit 10;
```

Comment: Wow!  That is clever.  And confusing.  When the `LIKE` _fails`, the `CASE` will give `NULL`, thereby letting the _second_ part (`desc`) take over.  _After_ those, the rest will be `asc`.

Comment: This solution gives you only 10 rows; is that what you want?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use `if` like this.  Start with this query:

```
SELECT s.ID_SPORTSMAN, s.NAME, s.SURNAME, s.SEX, s.CLUB, r.RESULTS 
FROM sportsman s JOIN
     results r
     ON s.ID_SPORTSMAN = r.ID_SPORTSMAN AND r.ID_DISCIPLINE = 1
ORDER BY r.RESULTS ASC
LIMIT 10;
```

And then work from there.

Notes:

- I removed `SELECT DISTINCT` because I doubt it is necessary.  If it is, use the `DISTINCT`.
- I replaced the table aliases with meaningful table abbreviations.  That makes the query much easier to follow.
- I simplified the `ORDER BY` clause so it should work.
- I removed the single quotes around "1", because it is presumably an integer.

You can modify this to get what you really want.

EDIT:

Hmmm, I think you might want this:

```
(SELECT s.ID_SPORTSMAN, s.NAME, s.SURNAME, s.SEX, s.CLUB, r.RESULTS 
 FROM sportsman s JOIN
      results r
      ON s.ID_SPORTSMAN = r.ID_SPORTSMAN AND r.ID_DISCIPLINE = 1
 WHERE s.RESULTS LIKE '`%'
 ORDER BY r.RESULTS ASC
 LIMIT 10
) UNION ALL
(SELECT s.ID_SPORTSMAN, s.NAME, s.SURNAME, s.SEX, s.CLUB, r.RESULTS 
 FROM sportsman s JOIN
      results r
      ON s.ID_SPORTSMAN = r.ID_SPORTSMAN AND r.ID_DISCIPLINE = 1
 WHERE s.RESULTS NOT LIKE '`%'
 ORDER BY r.RESULTS DESC
 LIMIT 10
);
```

Comment: I know it, but that's beside the question. I must usage IF, becouse records which have a sign `(tylda) I wan`t sort [z-a] and if havent this character i want sort [a-z]

Comment: The `UNION` gives you up to 10 from each group; is that what you want?